How make "Show More" button with Javascript and Flask For Loop in tables
I'm building an application for student consultation. In the admin tab I show the students who are registered through a table. However, I don't want to display them all at once, because that will make the page look cluttered.
That's why I want to display only 5 students and after clicking "Show all", the rest of the students will be displayed in the table.
I saw some tutorials for implementation with javascript, I managed to implement it using a simple html list, but when I try to use it with tables it doesn't work as expected.
With Lists I used this solution:
flask app:
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/'])
def home():
    array= ['test-1', 'test-2', 'test-3', 'test-4', 'test-5', 'test-6']
    return render_template('home.html', array=array)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)


HTML:
...
<ul>
      {% for item in array[:3] %}
        <li>{{ item }}</li>
      {% endfor %}

      <div class="show" style="display: none;">
        {% for item in lista[3:] %}
        <li>
          {{ item }}
        </li>
      {% endfor %}
      </div>
    </ul>

    <button class="buttonShow">Mostrar mais</button>
...

javascript:
<script>
      const buttonShow = document.getElementsByClassName("buttonShow")[0]
      const showItens = () => {
        document.getElementsByClassName("show")[0].style.display = "inline";
      }
      buttonShow.addEventListener('click', showItens)
    </script>

This works fine, I click in the button and the rest of the itens display.
I tried this same solution for the html tables, but the result was not as expected, instead of the students and their information appearing in new lines. All new rows appeared in a single table cell.
This is the table before I click the button:
enter image description here
And this is after I click the button:
enter image description here
The solution I tried to use for the tables was this:
Flask app:
@app.route('/admin')
@login_required
def admin():
    alunos = Aluno()
    users = User.query.all()
    admin = User.query.filter_by(id=current_user.id).first()
    if current_user.admin == 1:
        return render_template("admin.html", alunos=alunos, reversed=reversed)
    else:
        flash("You dont have access")
        return(redirect(url_for('home')))

Html:
<h2>New Students</h2>
          <table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Nome</th>
                <th>Curso</th>
                <th>Idade</th>
                <th>Pagamento</th>
                <th>Bolsa?</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>


            <tbody>
              {%for aluno in reversed(alunos.query.all()[-5:])%}
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <a href="{{url_for('aluno', aluno_id=aluno.id)}}"
                    >{{aluno.nome}}</a
                  >
                </td>
                <td>{{aluno.curso}}</td>
                <td>{{aluno.idade}}</td>
                <td>
                  {% for pag in aluno.pagamento %} 
                    {% if pag.pagamento %} 
                      Pago 
                    {% else %} 
                      Não Pago 
                    {% endif %} 
                  {% endfor %}
                </td>
                <td>
                  {% if aluno.bolsa %}
                    Possui Bolsa
                  {% else %}
                    Não Possui
                  {% endif %}
                </td>
              </tr>
              {%endfor%}

              <tr class="itens-toShow" style="display: none;">
                  {%for aluno in reversed(alunos.query.all()[0:-5])%}
                    <td>
                        <a href="{{url_for('aluno', aluno_id=aluno.id)}}"
                          >{{aluno.nome}}</a
                        >
                      </td>
                      <td>{{aluno.curso}}</td>
                      <td>{{aluno.idade}}</td>
                      <td>
                        {% for pag in aluno.pagamento %} 
                          {% if pag.pagamento %} 
                            Pay
                          {% else %} 
                            not pay 
                          {% endif %} 
                        {% endfor %}
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        {% if aluno.bolsa %}
                          Have
                        {% else %}
                          Dont Have
                        {% endif %}
                      </td>
                  {%endfor%}
              </tr>
              

            </tbody>

          </table>

Javascript:
let itemToshow = document.getElementsByClassName("itens-toShow")[0];
let buttonShow = document.getElementsByClassName("mostrar-itens")[0];

const mostrarMaisAlunos = () => {
    itemToshow.style.display = 'block';
    
};

buttonShow.addEventListener('click', mostrarMaisAlunos);

To exemplify the database I am using:
nome    curso     idade pagamento bolsa 
aluno1  jiujitsu  23      True      False 
aluno2  box       24      True      True 
aluno3  academy   24      False     True 
aluno4  jiujitsu  25      False     False 
aluno5  box       26      True      False

What am I doing wrong?

Is this different from your earlier question?

Yes, after the earlier question I tried to use with tables, and get stuck. (I forgot, I answered the last question right know, thanks for reminding me)

Move the <tr> element into the for-loop

Does not work. We i try this, just one item is shown and it's still in just one cell

If the db operation works, please hardcode the data for the purposes of this question so the code is runnable and reproducible. Thanks.

@ggorlen I put an example of the db content
